# Huge database with additional DB server

Tags: java, sql-server, database, performance, optimization

We have a big MS-SQL database with millions of records. There are java services which interacts with DB for data retrieval. The application deals with lot of LIKE, IN & JOIN clauses. This leads to higher CPU usage & longer response time during service call for java services.

Based on our analysis, we identified 4 big tables in DB which occupies lot of space. The decision is to add one more DB in a different server and allocate enough memory. Then move those 4 huge tables to a separate one from existing DB.

Can anyone please suggest will this idea help for DB optimization , making full use of two databases or any other helpful techniques?

Comment: you can try removing logic from your sql statement and put it in your java services. its not a very clean solution but it will take some pressure off of the db.

Comment: Hi @Todoy, We have only INNER JOIN & LIKE queries in Hibernate. Are you suggesting to split it into multiple queries? Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the existing server maxed out its CPUs? Often times CPU is not so much the issue but I/O capacity is (network, disks). You might be able to provide more I/O resources on your existing server and then distribute your temp db, tx logs, and potentially the four tables, across separate disks.

Splitting your schema across two servers will not be transparent to your Java clients. Also, if there are referential integrity constraints between those tables and the rest of the schema then you cannot do it unless you drop the constraints.

One alternative could be to use transcactional replication to replicate your complete schema across to another server. You could put both instances behind a load-balancer. Or you move all read-only processes to the replication.

Replications have their own downsides though. E.g. schema changes become harder because not all types of changes can be replicated. A stuck tx replication is a pain to resolve.

Before you start with any of this, make sure you have the appropriate indexes. The view sys.dm_db_missing_index_details can help you with that. Check out the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345434.aspx) to see how to query the view.

Comment: Hi @Ralf Thanks for your suggestions! We got an expert from Microsoft and he extracted all slow queries and suggested us to replace all LIKE with equal to. Other option we discussed was to move application specific queries to Stored procedures. Do you think it will help?

Comment: If you can live with the potential changes in results, then if course it is beneficial to change your LIKE operators to "=". You will get much better mileage from your indexes that way. Still you should check if you have all relevant indexes in place. Stored procedures... hard to say. I'd say you can profit from stored procs if you a) select massively more data than what the end-result would be and your clients condense it down before going about their business or b) your clients compute a result and write it right back to the DB without making further use of it themselves.